# R for loop scope in changing data frame column

Tags: r, dataframe

Currently having some difficulties trying to change a column within a data frame. As seen with the below code, my goal is to get the average background values for each unique `colA` factor (background value is marked by a boolean column). Using that, I need to create a new column by subtracting the `value` with the calculated average background.

I've tried using ifelse within the for loop, although I'm guessing that the for loop is using a shallow copy of my `df$val_no_bg`. Any suggestions on easier ways to do background subtraction or to solve this scoping issue?

```
df <- data.frame(colA = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                background = c(T, T, F, F, T, T, F, F),
                value = c(10:17))

bg <- df[df$background, ]
bg_compiled <- aggregate(bg[, "value"], list(bg$colA), mean)

df$val_no_bg <- NA
for (i in nrow(bg_compiled$Group.1)) {
  change <- which(df$colA == bg_compiled[i, "Group.1"])
  df[change, "val_no_bg"] <- df[change, "value"] - bg_compiled[i, "x"]  
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the desired output for this input? That will make it easier to test possible alternatives.

Comment: for loops run in the global environment. I think MrFlick has a good answer for you below :)

Comment: @DanHall - I'm relatively new to R, so I imagine that for loops are not the preferred way of working with data frames?

Comment: Most of the time, for several reasons. I still write them when I'm tired or have just switched from working for several hours in another language. But when you try writing a for loop, you might find it helpful to try rethinking your problem in a way that takes advantage of the structure of objects in R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do this fairly easily with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(background) %>%
  mutate(val_no_bg = value - mean(value))
```

Comment: There's no "scoping" problem at all. Your problem really was in `nrow(bg_compiled$Group.1)`. If you run that, you see it's NULL so your loop never runs. You either wanted `for (i in 1:nrow(bg_compiled))` or `for (i in 1:length(bg_compiled$Group.1))`

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can use `ave` to calculate a column of mean values that you can then use...

```
df$BGAv <- ave(df$value, df$colA, df$background, FUN=mean)

df
  colA background value BGAv
1    A       TRUE    10 10.5
2    A       TRUE    11 10.5
3    A      FALSE    12 12.5
4    A      FALSE    13 12.5
5    B       TRUE    14 14.5
6    B       TRUE    15 14.5
7    B      FALSE    16 16.5
8    B      FALSE    17 16.5
```

If you just want the means by `colA` and not by `background` as well, then omit the third argument.

You can then calculate `df$val_no_bg <- df$value - df$BGAv`